Impossible to grab an href link using requests or Selenium
My goal is to extract all the href links from this page and find the .pdf links. I tried using the requests library and Selenium, but neither of them could extract it.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you.
Ex: This contain a .pdf file link

This is the request code:
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0'}
    url="https://www.bain.com/insights/topics/energy-and-natural-resources-report/"
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))

This is the selenium code:
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

    page_source = driver.get("https://www.bain.com/insights/topics/energy-and-natural-resource-report/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))

    driver.quit()


It has the look of a  element which usually triggers a JS method or form post.  Check for form action or a javascript ajax/fetch call.

When I run the ‘requests’ code I get that the response code is 404, and also same when I try to access the site manually…

Code is working fine with me

Browsermator: How can I check such a thing?

Here is the python-requests version how to get all pdfs from that page:
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def find_pdfs(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            if k == "url" and ".pdf" in v:
                yield v
            else:
                yield from find_pdfs(v)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for v in data:
            yield from find_pdfs(v)


url = "https://www.bain.com/insights/topics/energy-and-natural-resources-report/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
iframe_src = soup.iframe["src"]
iframe_text = requests.get(iframe_src).text

doc = re.search(r"docVersion: (.*}),", iframe_text).group(1)
doc = json.loads(doc)

data = requests.get(doc["committedJsonUrl"]).text
data = re.search(r"(\{.*\})\);", data).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
pdfs = set(find_pdfs(data))
print(*pdfs, sep="\n")

Prints:
https://www.bain.com/globalassets/noindex/2022/bain_report_global-private-equity-report-2022.pdf
https://www.bain.com/globalassets/noindex/2023/bain_report_engineering_and_r_and_d_report_2023.pdf
https://www.bain.com/globalassets/noindex/2023/bain_report_energy_and_natural_resources_2023.pdf


Wow, this works perfectly fine. Thank you, Andrej. But why does this happen with iframes? Are there any other syntaxes like iframes that block me from extracting href links?

@dfcsdf I'm not well versed with selenium, but <iframe> seems to require special handling: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/

Appreciate your insight. Thank you.

The HTML of the link is

<a id="64dcc36471af7" ... href="https://www.bain.com/globalassets/noindex/2023/bain_report_energy_and_natural_resources_2023.pdf">

You can use the CSS selector below to locate the download link,
a[href*='pdf']

This selector is just looking for an A tag that contains the string "pdf" in the href attribute.
I don't know if this affects BeautifulSoup like it does Selenium but the link is in an IFRAME. The locator for the IFRAME is
iframe[title='v1_ENR Report 2023_ToC']


Appreciate your insight. Thank you.
